# How to use custom pipes on Ionic2 - A2 project?

Tags: angular, filter, ionic2, pipe

I want to filter with a pipe a simple list generated by a *ngFor.
This is my relevant tree folder:

```
src
 |_app
    |_app.component.ts
    |_app.module.ts
 |_pages
     |_home.ts
     |_home.html
 |_pipes
     |_pipe.ts
```

Here is my code:

**My pipe.ts:**(Just a regular iDoNothing)

```
import {Pipe} from "angular2/core";

@Pipe({
    name:"search"
})

export class SearchPipe{
    transform(value){
        return value;
    }
}
```

**My home.ts**(The one and only page displayed)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { SearchPipe } from '../pipes/search-pipes';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  pipes:[SearchPipe] //Here is where i got the error
})
export class HomePage {

  posts: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {

    this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json').map(
      res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = data.data.children;
      });

  }
}
```

**My home template** (home.html)

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home Page</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts | search">
      <h2>{{post.data.title}}</h2>
      <img [src]="post.data.url" />
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

To resume, basically I am declaring a pipe in **pipe.ts**, importing it in **home.ts** and displaying it in **home.html** but it return this error :

> Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; pipes: any[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'. Object
>   literal may only specify known properties, and 'pipes' does not exist
>   in type 'Component'.

Is there any options to declare more @Component properties that I am missing?
After I successfully add the imports will I be able to use it on every item of the list

Comment: [The docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html) show the list of metadata attributes for a `@Component`, and `pipes` is indeed not on it. A pipe is a *declaration*, and you should provide it through the module not the component.